# Large Gesturedetectors are blocking my SingleChildScrollView from scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I have large clickable cards in a list, they take up 90% of the width.

A SingleChildScrollView is wrapping a listview that builds the cards.

Problem is, due to the gesturedetectors being large, it's difficult to scroll the list. Scrolling on the cards doesn't do anything since it's own onTap is conflicting with it.

Is there any way to solve this without disabling the onTap for GestureDetectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the behavior to your GestureDetector:

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the size is determined by shrinkwrap in a listview. However, if I wrap the list in a container with fixed size, it works.

Comment: @Jocko Didn't work with shrinkwrap cause i had a scroll inside of a scroll, adding physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), in list fixed it.